# Modify all leaf nodes of JSON file with gulp

Tags: json, angularjs, gulp, angular-translate

I'm using angular-translate, and have a number of JSON files containing the translation strings and I already have it setup with json-combine to merge all of the individual files together into a single file for each language. The resulting file looks like this:

```
{
  "myNamespace" : {
    "CANCEL" : "Cancel",
    "PENDING" : "Pending", 
    "module" : {
      "USERNAME" : "User name",
      "PASSWORD" : "Password"
    }
  }
}
```

However, I have the need to add characters to the start and end of each of the translation strings in order to perform testing that there aren't any hard-coded strings anywhere in the application, and can't seem to figure out how to do this.

I could manually modify each of the strings and create a separate language file, but I would prefer to do it programmatically, and AFTER the rest of the gulp tasks. Basically it should take the fully combined English file and modify each of the leaf-nodes to look like this:

```
{
  "myNamespace" : {
    "CANCEL" : "\u4ECFCancel\u7D42",
    "PENDING" : "\u4ECFPending\u7D42", 
    "module" : {
      "USERNAME" : "\u4ECFUser name\u7D42",
      "PASSWORD" : "\u4ECFPassword\u7D42"
    }
  }
}
```

Is this possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this on my own, using the following gulp task:

```
gulp.task("i18n-pseudo-locale", function() {
    return gulp.src(distDirectory + "/l10n/en_US.json")
        .pipe(jsoncombine(pseudoLocale + ".json", function(data) {
            var originalJson = data["en_US"];
            function processJson(json) {
                // Leaf node
                if (typeof(json) === "string") {
                    return "\u4ECF" + json +  "s\u7D42";
                }
                // object
                for(var propertyName in json) {
                    json[propertyName] = processJson(json[propertyName]);
                }
                return json;
            }
            finalJson = processJson(originalJson);
            return new Buffer(JSON.stringify(finalJson));
         }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(distDirectory + "/l10n"));
});
```